# SHA encyption (help me)

Tags: encryption

OK, so I am a real noob at cryptography stuff and I have a set of files. One is a string that I am trying to decrypt, and the other has this

SHA: 4534e95cb5f001719a6119a092459dc826965d60

Can I use this to decrypt the string I have? And if so, how?

I probably sound really stupid but I need help.

Answer (score 2):

Decryption is off topic, but I will explain why your question is meaningless.

SHA is a one way unkeyed hash function not an encryption primitive. In correct use you feed in a string [maybe your other string] to SHA algorithm (whichever version was used, yours looks like 160 bit SHA) and if you get the same output as this string that means the original string is *correct*, i.e., was used to generate this SHA output and was not tampered with.